# Add Item to a IEnumerable populated using Linq (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to get some values from a datatable to use them as a filter. 
I extract the values and later I populate a combobox's datasource.

The problem is, I want to add an extra item that will act like the option "all" and I'm stuck at this point.

My code:

```
Dim objFilter As IEnumerable
objFilter = From obj In m_DataSet.Tables(0) _
                              Select New With {Key .Cod = obj.Field(Of String)("X"), _
                                                   .Desc = obj.Field(Of String)("Y")} Distinct.ToList

Me.combobox.DataSource = ienCentrosOrigen
Me.combobox.ValueMember = "Cod"
Me.combobox.DisplayMember = "Desc"
```

I've tried using "union" like this:

```
objFilter = From obj In m_DataSet.Tables(0) _
                              Select New With {Key .Cod = obj.Field(Of String)("X"), _
                                                   .Desc = obj.Field(Of String)("Y")} Distinct..Union(New With {Key .Cod = "-1", .Desc = "All"}).ToList
```

but it does not work:

> Runtime errors might occur when converting 'anonymous type (line 1147)' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of anonymous type)'.

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are selecting already a `List` you can use `List.Add`. But you have declared it as `IEnumerable` which doesn't have `Add` (or `Remove`). So just use `Dim` without a type and the compiler will infer the correct (List)-type:

```
Dim objFilter = From obj In m_DataSet.Tables(0)
            Select New With {
                Key .Cod = obj.Field(Of String)("X"),
                    .Desc = obj.Field(Of String)("Y")}
            Distinct.ToList()
objFilter.Add(New With {Key .Cod = "-1", .Desc = "All"})
' or at the beginning:
objFilter.Insert(0, New With {Key .Cod = "-1", .Desc = "All"})
```

Comment: Is there any way of specifying the type?? Just to avoid the warning message: _Variable declaration without an 'As' clause; type of Object assumed._

Comment: @Aldipa: what Visual Studio version are you using? You should set  [`Option Infer On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx) ( project-wide or better VB-Standard).

Comment: Visual Studio 2008. Thank you it Works perfect!